# Griffon upgrade: dealing with startup arguments

Tags: arguments, upgrade, griffon

I'm upgrading a big 0.3.1 Griffon app into 0.9.4 I'm getting these difficulties:

- **Startup arguments**:
  I needed to deal with startup arguments so there was (in previous version) a:

  class MyApplication extends SwingApplication

now it seems this can be accomplished in a cleaner way using:

`app.getStartupArgs()`

where should I put my own code? in **Initialize.groovy** script perhaps?

Any post or example on how to deal with these arguments?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing `app.getStartupArgs()` can be done from anywhere you have access to the `app` variable. Remember that lifecycle scripts are **always** executed inside the EDT, no exceptions.

Personally I tend to use application events more and more, for example reading the startup args after all startup mvc groups have been created can be done like this (in a file named `griffon-app/conf/Events.groovy`)

```
onStartupEnd = { app ->
    println app.startupArgs
}
```